# Send envelope to another recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send a DocuSign envelope, that has already been sent to a customer (not signed yet), to another or a new customer. This is slightly different from resending the contract, but the same envelope is being resent to a new contact.

Is this possible? I have tried all sorts of things, like change the recipient details to new contact, add new sender to the existing recipient details.

The document is sent to the original sender fine, but to the new sender, the tab information is missing and the sign here tab is not there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check/accept the best answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replacing the original recipient** :
The original recipient can be replaced with a new recipient using the [UpdateEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) api.

The original recipient will no longer have access to the envelope.

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

{
 "signers": [
  {
   "recipientId": 1,
   "email": "newsigner@acme.com",
   "name": "New Signer",
  }
 ]
}
```

---

**Adding a new recipient**: To add a new recipient in addition to the existing recipients, use the [CreateEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/) api.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

{
  "signers": [
    {
      "recipientId": 2,
      "email": "newsigner@acme.com",
      "name": "New Signer"
    }
  ]
}
```

To Add tabs to the new recipient, use the [CreateEnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/) api. Make sure you specify the recipientId correctly in the Url.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

{
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "120",
        "yPosition": "120",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this solution, but I get a corrected email back to the original sender.. Is there anyway I can avoid that? I retain the tab info for the new recipient though.. Cheers..

Comment: Looks like you want to add a new recipient with new tabs and also keep the original recipient. Is that correct?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, the first option, solved our problem, we can work around with that corrected email.. cheers